# Can I really discuss the validity of closure of my question here?

Tags: discussion, meta, help-center

As per the [official help center page on reopening questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions), it states

> If you're simply unsure about the validity of the closure, the best place to ask is on the community's meta site. Asking in the meta site allows those who took the action to comment, and will help others to learn about the issues being discussed.

However when I tried to do this, [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385657/why-was-my-question-closed-as-off-topic?noredirect=1#comment1286081_385657) that was questioning the validity of another one of my questions was closed as off-topic with the moderator saying that my post will not be answered on this site. Furthermore there are many questions on this site that also discuss the validity of closure of their questions, which are not closed.

Comment: You're quoting from the Stack Overflow help page. And the quote says "on the community's meta site". The meta site for Stack Overflow is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Which dosen't quite explain why it was asked here... https://serverfault.com/help/reopen-questions is the equivilent for server fault and that points at SF meta.

Comment: If there really are many questions on here discussing the closure/reopening of server fault questions, start flagging those. They need to be closed as well then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"On the community's meta site" - in this case meta.serverfault.com based off your other question. Meta site URLs may vary by site. Discoverability isn't great for per site metas but main meta's probably not the right place.

Comment: Thank you, it was not immediately clear to me that sites have their own meta subdomains from the help page, I will ask there

Comment: I have opinions on this - and really feel like the links to that and chat should be more obvious. I think this is another example of why hiding it in the SE site switcher is ... insufficient

Comment: There's no obvious link in the Help articles to get to meta either. The  article quoted in the question links only to "what's meta", and there are no above-the-fold links there (though I am on mobile currently). I would have stopped reading before I found the first link to the site meta. And if you're googling, you'll see links to 1) the site meta, 2) here, 3) possibly Meta Stack Overflow. Very confusing for someone who doesn't know about the structure of metas. (As for chat, you're better off leaving 20 comments on a post to attract so that a mod forces you to go to chat :p)